# Having trouble embedding audio with HTML from OneDrive - why will audio only play from temp files, and how to fix for public use?

Tags: html, audio, onedrive, twine-game-engine

I'm making my first Twine game as part of a portfolio, and I wanted to include background music that autoplayed using HTML. I've been linking images from OneDrive fine, but the only way I can get the music to play once I've published my file is to link it directly to music files that I've manually placed into my Temp folder. No other method seems to get the audio to play, forgetting looping or autoplaying, and my school is unable to provide any help.

I'd be happy with the audio playing from temp files, but the university admission staff will be sent the contents of the portfolio and I would like for them to be able to hear the music when they play.

I tried following a step-by-step guide which involved copying the mp3 file's embed code from OneDrive, shortening it to 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=333595D0658FC4C8&resid=333595D0658FC4C8%21126&authkey=AEqQ78ZqrqVd7i8' (replacing the 'embed?' with 'download?'), and putting it into the following form:

`<audio src="https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=333595D0658FC4C8&resid=333595D0658FC4C8%21126&authkey=AEqQ78ZqrqVd7i8"></audio>`

I can't tell what's wrong with this - any ideas of what to try instead would be much appreciated!